# generate url to feature in aws console of a specific account

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, redirect, hyperlink

I'm looking to a way to generate urls/links to specific resources of a given account in the AWS console website.

For instance I want to link to the summary view of a given user in IAM.
The resource URL is the following:

`https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/users/user.name`

All good, but how do I force the browser to authenticate in the correct AWS account?

As as hypothetical example:

`https://account-name.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/users/user.name`

On the other hand, knowing that sending the user to:

`https://account-name.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/`

Will trigger the login process for the "account-name" account, how can I send the user to a specific part of the AWS console afterwords?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "force the browser to authenticate in the correct AWS account", are you wanting it to prompt for a matching password, or are you wanting it to take users directly to the console _as that logged-in user_ (eg using Federation)?

Comment: from my application user stand point:
when I click a user from the list, I want to be taken to the AWS console web interface, to the summary view of the user I clicked, being forced(or not if am already loged in) to login in the AWS console with my user for the given account

Comment: I'm still confused. Do you want to use _your IAM User_ to view the _selected_ IAM User in the console, or are you saying you want to be _logged in_ as the selected user? (I'm not sure what you meant by "given account").

Comment: The backoffice I am making is listing users of multiple AWS accounts, let's say the backoffice manages multiple clients of mine.
When you login in the aws console you have to input the account (account id or alias), IAM user name and password. The problem is linking to a IAM summary view of a user in a given AWS account. Usecase: I'm logged in on AWS console for client A, but in the backoffice I click on a user that belongs to client B, if I link directly to user user it will give me a not found, since it doesn't belong to the account A, how do I force the browser to login into B, if possible

Comment: The closest I know is using an Alias to the account, as displayed in the IAM console, eg: `https://my-alias.signin.aws.amazon.com/console`. Let's see if anyone can suggest something better.

Comment: From my tests, the method you describe also works with the account numeric ID, yep lets hope there is a better solution. Thank you for your input

Comment: I'd also like to generate a link to a specific page for a specific feature for a specific account. Did you find a way?

Comment: Nop, I have no new information about it

Answer (score 2):

Add `iam_user=true&account=<id>&` right after `?` and before `#` sign.

e.g.:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?iam_user=true&account=111222333444#/users/user.name

Comment: From my testing this seems to work.
I would love to have more feedback before accepting as the answer

Comment: this does not work for me; for context I'm using SAML auth to AWS. When I use a link like this I am taken to the URL of whatever account I was already logged in to.

Comment: @drobert it looks like that's a different use case. If I understand correctly, you want it to send you to sign in screen of account2 even if you're currently signed in to account1.
I don't know if that's even possible without signing out first.

Comment: adding just `account=<id>` was sufficient for my use case to redirect to a specific S3 bucket.

Comment: @JoshPeak just in case try it in an incognito browser, I noticed that sometimes AWS defaults to the other sign in UI without account id.

Comment: @pmoleri oh yeah you’re right! Thanks.  I’ll update the bookmarks and internal docs I’ve made. Our internal docs cite this answer anyhow.  I have used this as a low tech way for non-tech users to upload adhoc files for analysis in a locked down landing zone AWS account without me having to build out a UI. The dropped files get ingested into the data warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples that worked for me, if I use real account number (or account alias) for the S3 and CloudFormation services. I didn't find the official documentation that it works for every service but try it.

- https://0123456789.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/s3/?bucket=fake-bucket-0123456789

  This redirects me to the S3 bucket named "fake-bucket-0123456789"
- https://0123456789.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/cloudformation

  This redirects me to Cloudformation

Comment: Does not work with cloudwatch unfortunately.